# What is the difference between wmain and main?

Tags: c++, c, windows, program-entry-point, wmain

So I have some class starting with

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and there is a `wmain` function .

How is it different from main function i usually use in my C/C++ programs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"If your code adheres to the Unicode programming model, you can use the wide-character version of main, which is wmain."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299386%28VS.60%29.aspx

```
main( int argc, char *argv[ ], char *envp[ ] )
{
program-statements
}

wmain( int argc, wchar_t *argv[ ], wchar_t *envp[ ] )
{
program-statements
}
```

Answer (score 22):

The difference between `main` and `wmain` is the type used to represent the arguments to the program.  The `main` function uses normal `char` while `wmain` uses `wchar_t` which can accept unicode values

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299386(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 2):

main is the normal program entry point in c & c++ and is passed the command line in single byte characters. wmain is an alternative that is used in many windows programs for unicode programs where it instead gets passed the command line as wide 16 bit unicode characters.

I believe it's a windows extension for unicode programs.