# Can we use wmain() with Unix compilers or it'll work only on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, unix, widestring, wmain

Can we use the `wmain()` function with Unix compilers or it'll work only on/for Windows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only standard signatures for `main` are:

```
int main(void);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

However, a freestanding implementation can provide extensions/allow other signatures. But those are not guranteed to be portable. `wmain` looks like a Windows/VS thing. There's not much chance this will work on a *nix/GNU GCC.

Answer (score 14):

The `wmain` signature exists in Windows to handle wide-character command line arguments. Generally, while Windows applications prefer UTF16, Unix applications prefer UTF8 for Unicode string encoding. UTF8 uses regular `char` character strings, so the standard `main` signature suffices for Unicode-aware Unix appications.

If you want to make a portable console application that does not require Unicode command line parameters, use `main`. If you do need Unicode command line parameters, then you need preprocessor directives that will enable the signature appropriate to each environment.

If you are making a cross-platform GUI application, use a special framework, like Qt.

Answer (score 4):

The only standard forms of `main` are

> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714)

All others are non-standard. If you read the document from MS you'll see that `wmain` is put in the *Microsoft Specific* section:

> ## Microsoft Specific
>
> If your source files use Unicode wide characters, you can use `wmain`, which is the wide-character version of main. The declaration syntax for wmain is as follows:
>
> ```
> int wmain( );
> int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[], wchar_t *envp[]);
> ```
>
> You can also use `_tmain`, which is defined in tchar.h. `_tmain` resolves to `main` unless `_UNICODE` is defined. In that case, `_tmain` resolves to `wmain`.
>
> [main function and command-line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019)

Its main purpose is to get Unicode parameters such as file names. However it's quite useless and most people don't actually use it because you can just call [`GetCommandLineW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew) and [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) to get the same thing without any changes to main's signature

For portability you can use [Boost.Nowide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/nowide/doc/html/index.html) so that everything is in UTF-8. Newer Windows 10 and MSVC's standard library also support setting UTF-8 as the active code page and you can get Unicode args with `GetCommandLineA` or sometimes with the normal `main`. See [What is the Windows equivalent for en_US.UTF-8 locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714)

See also

- [What is the difference between wmain and main?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2438049/995714)

Answer (score 3):

`wmain()` is windows-specific. Just like `_tmain`, if that matters...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if by "Unix compilers" you mean you are using compilers in Unix, but not necessarily compiling Unix targets. You can pass `-municode` to GCC when cross-compiling to Windows targets to make `wmain` and `wWinMain` work. But still it can't make these main functions work for *nix targets.