# Eclipse character set like Visual C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-c++, unicode, eclipse-cdt

In Visual C++ you can set the character set to **Use Unicode Character Set**.
Which defines *UNICODE* and *_UNICODE*.

In Eclipse CDT is there anyway to accomplish the same effect?

Answer (score 2):

I think :  Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace ..

Answer (score 2):

The `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE` macro are using by Microsoft Visual C++ compiler only. So, it is not crossplatform way to add Unicode support to your programs.
Eclipse CDT use mingw, which is Windows port of GCC.
So, you can try this: http://site.icu-project.org/, or just use Qt framework - which have rich support for internationalization, and do most of job for you.
Hope this helps.

Comment: No. The macros are used by any C++ compiler when compiling `<windows.h>`. They're not magical in any way.

Comment: Hm, the CRT and STL implementation must also use these macro. So, if you only include <windows.h> in you mingw-oriented program, you don't have Unicode. See http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/16820/

Comment: The STL doesn't use it (doesn't need it) as it offers `std::string` and `std::wstring`. As your link notes, if you want a `UNICODE`-dependent `tstring`, you have to define it yourself. The CRT also works without it. Furthermore, even if you don't use the macro, you can still explicitly call `MessageBoxW(L"Hello world")` to get a Unicode message box, and that works equally well with mingw.

Comment: How would you tell the linker to use wmain? On the simplest "hello world", I have a linker error 'undefined reference to main'. I don't have have 'main' I've 'wmain'. Is that supported in g++?

Comment: @Uri http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438297/can-we-use-wmain-functions-with-unix-compilers-or-itll-work-only-on-windows i.e. no support for wmain in gcc.