# Compiling wmain under cygwin

Tags: unicode, g++, cygwin, program-entry-point

I'm trying to compile c++ code with the following main definition:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t** argv)
```

I can compile it correctly with Visual Studio, but g++ fails with the following error messages:

```
g++ -municode -o l1bCorrector AappL1bCorrector/l1bCorrector.o -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lScanexUtilities -Wl,-Bdynamic
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.17-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39: undefined reference to `_WinMain@16'
```

Comment: Look this: [Can we use wmain() functions with Unix compilers or it'll work only on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438297/can-we-use-wmain-functions-with-unix-compilers-or-itll-work-only-on-windows).

Answer (score 3):

GCC has no support for `wmain` (even mingw GCC, which I expect to be the best in this respect).

If you need unicode command-line arguments as an array, you can use `CommandLineToArgvW` on the result of `GetCommandLineW`.

Comment: Is it possible to use unicode parameters in ANY way without platform-dependent code?

Comment: Not when targetting Windows and non-Windows simultaneously. We could just use `mbrtowc` on `argv[..]`, but on Windows, `argv[..]` has already lost some information from the start.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko, does this mean that I can't use any unicode related functions like `CreateFileW` and etc?