# using wchar_t in the main function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Is it wrong to use the main function in C++ Visual Studio 2017 as following:

```
int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
```

as my program can receive special characters.

Comment: Yes it's wrong since that's now how `main` is supposed to be declared. If you're on Windows and using Visual Studio and its compiler look into using `wmain` instead (as [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx)).

Comment: @OP do you have `int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv)` or `int main(int argc, wchar_t** argv)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between wmain and main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438049/what-is-the-difference-between-wmain-and-main)

Comment: @NathanOliver The OPs `wchar_t *argv[]` is exactly the same as `wchar_t **argv`.

Comment: @Swordfish The Q was edited by another user.  Originally the user had `int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv)` which is not the same

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry then.

Answer (score 6):

Please go and read the remarks section on [`GetCommandLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx?appid=dev15idef1&l=en-us&k=k(getcommandlinew)%3bk(devlang-c%2b%2b)%3bk(targetos-windows)&rd=true):

> ANSI console processes written in C can use the argc and argv arguments of the main function to access the command-line arguments. ANSI GUI applications can use the lpCmdLine parameter of the WinMain function to access the command-line string, excluding the program name. The main and WinMain functions cannot return Unicode strings.
>
> Unicode console process written in C can use the `wmain()` or `_tmain()` function to access the command-line arguments. Unicode GUI applications must use the GetCommandLineW function to access Unicode strings.
>
> To convert the command line to an argv style array of strings, call the CommandLineToArgvW function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but if you need to perform input and output operations, perhaps you need to add `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`, because by default it only supports the most basic English character output.
example:

```cpp
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
  std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wstring str = argv[1]; //if argv[1] contains unicode characters, such as"你好"
  wcout << str << endl;
  return 0;
}
```