# Type conversion from string to const wchar_t* . Type does not match

Tags: c++, types

Hi i have the following  function which i want to call:

```
uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const wchar_t* modName)
```

Now i want to write a support function which takes a given string and converts it to the
target parameter `'const wchar_t* modName'`

I have the folloing function:

```
wchar_t* stringToWchar(std::string s) {
  std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(s.begin(), s.end());
  const wchar_t* widestr = widestr.c_str();
  return widestr;
}
```

at the return line i get the error: `"no suitable conversion function from to exists"`.

What do i miss here?

In the final result i want to make a call like:

```
GetModuleBaseAddress(procId, stringToWchar("module.exe"))
```

Thx.

Comment: That's not going to work: your std::wstring in stringToWchar is on the stack and is only valid until you leave the function, ditto the c_str pointer. Nor is that the correct character conversion for a non-ASCII string (or possibly non-Latin1). But it also won't compile because you've got two variables called widestr in the function.

Comment: Can you do simply `GetModuleBaseAddress(procId, L"module.exe")`? Or is your actual problem more complex?

Comment: its a simple problem i have an input parameter from a console application, but i cant call GetModuleBaseAddress(procId, argv[2]);

Comment: So use std::wcin if you need wide characters.

Comment: Can you use `wmain` in place of `main`? (The latter has a `wchar_t` type for `argv`.) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2438049/10871073).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your function to return a `wstring`

```
std::wstring stringToWchar(std::string s) {
    return std::wstring(s.begin(), s.end());
}
```

then use it like this

```
GetModuleBaseAddress(procId, stringToWchar("module.exe").c_str());
```

Your code was attempting to return a pointer to an object which no longer exists (`widestr`). You also declared the variable `widestr` twice, and you attempted to remove the `const` qualifier.

Don't program with pointers if you can help it. If you need a pointer for some third party API then generate the pointer at the point you call the third party function, not before.